# How do I install Go on CentOS 5.7?

Tags: centos5

I'm trying to install go language from http://golang.org
(I'm planning to make a web server with this)

But right now I get these messages when I install exactly as the official documents says:

http://pastebin.com/yHPsHgN8

Does anyone have any idea on how to install Go on CentOS?

I have already installed the Development Tools package using yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the development packages installed.

http://golang.org/doc/install.html has a list of Ubuntu packages.  You'll need to find the equivalent CentOS packages and install those.

Something like `yum install glibc-devel glibc-headers bison bison-devel` and so on.